# Hide a path node in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following url:

```
http://example.com/dr/2015/10/pic.jpg
```

where 2015/10/pic.jpgis dynamic: 2015 is the year, 10 is the month number and pic.jpg a file name. Every time an image is sent, the year and month folders are created as the current date.

I would like to remove the node "dr" of the url, like the example below:

```
http://example.com/2015/10/pic.jpg
```

I found this question, which is the closest to what I need: https://superuser.com/questions/435916/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-path-node

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This rule will internally redirect /2015/10/pic.jpg to /dr/2015/10/pic.jpg but URL will be /2015/10/pic.jpg

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/pic.jpg dr/$1/$2/pic.jpg last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it to your `try_files`. This is the simplest and will perform better than a `rewrite`. For example:

```
try_files /dr$uri $uri ....the rest of it...
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of previous answers, I reached the following result:

```
location ~ /dr {
      #empty
}

location / {
      rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /dr/$1/$2/$3 last;
}
```

It works well for what I need.